# how to optimize performances of geometry operations

Tags: python, computational-geometry, shapely

I am looking for an approach to optimize performances of geometry operations. My goal is to count how many points (205,779) within a series of polygons (21,562). Using python and R are preferable as well as GIS software, like ArcGIS, QGIS.

Here are solutions I have searched and written.

1. using ArcGIS: one of examples is in http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/30779 -> although I did not try it, it always take a large amount of time in spatial join, based on my previous experiences.
2. using GDAL, OGR: Here is an example: http://geoexamples.blogspot.tw/2012/06/density-maps-using-gdalogr-python.html -> It takes 5 to 9 seconds for every polygon.
3. using Shapely prepared geometry operations with a loop: Here is my example, and it takes 2.7 to 3.0 seconds for every polygon. (Note that points is Point objects in a list)

   ```
   prep_poly=[]
   for i in polygons:
       mycount=[]
       for j in points:
           if prep(i).contains(j):
               mycount.append(1) #count how many points within polygons
       prep_poly.append(sum(mycount)) #sum once for every polygon
       mycount=[]
   ```
4. using Shapely prepared geometry operations with a filter: Here is my example, and it takes about 3.3 to 3.9 seconds for every polygon.(Note that points is a MultiPoint object)

   ```
   prep_poly=[]
   for i in polygons:
       prep_poly.append(len(filter(prep(i).contains, point1)))
   ```

Though prepared geometry operations did improve the performances, it is still time-consuming to process lots of polygons. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looking through every pixel on the screen for every rectangle, you can do the following (Python code):

```
first_pixel = any pixel in the polygon
px_list = [] # array with pixels left to check
px_list.append(first_pixel) # add pixel to list of pixels to process

count = 0

while len(array) > 0: # pixels left in pixel list
    curr_pixel = array[0]
    for pixel in get_adjacent_pixels(curr_pixel): # find adjacent pixels
                                                  # ie (vertical, horizontal, diagonal)
        if pixel in shape:
            px_list.append(pixel) # add pixel to list

    px_list.remove(curr_pixel)
    count += 1
```

Essentially, the same way that path finding works. Check this wiki article for a visual representation of the above algorithm:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Algorithm

If you have no easy way to find starting points you could loop through all of the points once, checking for each point whether it is contained by a shape, and then storing that point together with the shape in a separate list and deleting it from the original shapes-for-which-we-have-no-point-yet list.